# Trying to understand C# TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand C# `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` and I wrote this simple example. I expect the continuation task to not run because there was no exception in the antecedent task but it runs anyway.

```
var task = Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello world!"); })
    .ContinueWith((x, y) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This should not get printed!");
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look more closely at what overloads exist for `ContinueWith()`, and especially what overload you're actually calling.

There is no overload for `ContinueWith()` that takes only a delegate and a `TaskContinuationOptions` value specifically. The overload you're calling takes as parameters an `Action<Task, object>`, and then *any* `object` value, which is the "state" value passed to the `Action<Task, object>`. That state value has no effect whatsoever on what `ContinueWith()` actually does. It just passes that value to your delegate.

If you want to use the `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` value to actually control the behavior of the `ContinueWith()` method, you need to use an overload that includes that parameter type specifically.

The easiest way to fix your code would be to simply pass `null` as the state value for the `ContinueWith(Action<Task, object>, object, TaskContinuationOptions)` overload:

```
var task = Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello world!"); })
    .ContinueWith((x, y) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This should not get printed!");
    }, null, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Do note that in this case, your `task` object will get canceled after the first task finishes rather than executing the continuation (by design, of course).